# Android WebView play video error blink black screen

Tags: android, video, webview, screen, blink

Hi i am writing an application from webview and when playing video in webview sometimes an error occurs and the phone screen starts flickering white-black.

watch the screen recording https://youtu.be/ST8fc0w_Um8

and in the log android studio

```
2020-07-30 11:14:51.575 32584-310/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:image_reader_gl_owner.cc(263)] no buffers currently available in the reader queue
2020-07-30 11:14:51.613 32584-310/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(471)] CreateSharedImage: could not create backing.
2020-07-30 11:14:51.614 32584-310/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_stub.cc(169)] SharedImageStub: Unable to create shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.624 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(141)] SharedImageManager::ProduceGLTexture: Trying to produce a representation from a non-existent mailbox. 48:86:2E:E3:73:35:1E:70:B4:F7:83:AD:17:E1:CE:8F
2020-07-30 11:14:51.624 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18937)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoCreateAndTexStorage2DSharedImageINTERNAL: invalid mailbox name
2020-07-30 11:14:51.624 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18958)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoBeginSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.624 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18987)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.624 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18958)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoBeginSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.625 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10716)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incompatible texture filtering (maybe)?
2020-07-30 11:14:51.626 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18987)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:B89A0D1A74000000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.712 32584-310/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_factory.cc(471)] CreateSharedImage: could not create backing.
2020-07-30 11:14:51.712 32584-310/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_stub.cc(169)] SharedImageStub: Unable to create shared image
2020-07-30 11:14:51.729 32584-32643/ru.example E/chromium: [ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(141)] SharedImageManager::ProduceGLTexture: Trying to produce a representation from a non-existent mailbox. 7E:1A:65:59:81:24:B8:07:83:A5:48:04:2B:51:A5:59
```

My webview settings

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        WebView = (ObservableWebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.WebView);

        WebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        WebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);

        WebView.setFocusable(true);
        WebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);


        WebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        WebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        WebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        ///WebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        //WebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                if(appBarHeight==0){
                    appBarHeight=((MainActivity) getContext()).getHeightPanel();
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

        });
        WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptBridge(WebView), "Android");
```

Please help with this problem

Comment: I have a similar problem. My stacktrace is nearly the same. I tried to comment out every  line one by one, and eventually figured out that my custom implementation of WebChromeClient causes the issue. But I'm not still sure what the problem is

Comment: I see this error today. its related to google chrome update. In previous versions of google chrome it's not happening. I will report that to google.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: This chromium / webview bug is here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1109016